# jsonresult does not come back?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

trying to display a success message from the controller?

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SuccesMsg()
    {
        return Json(new { Success = true });
    }
```

jquery:

```
        $("#but").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/SuccesMsg",
                type: 'POST',
                data: "",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (resultJson['Success'] == true) {
                        alert('success');
                    }

                    else
                    { alert('no'); }
                },
                error: function (err) { alert('error') }
            });
        });
```

Comment: what's the response you see in firebug?

Comment: what is `resultJson`? Are any of the alerts showing?

Comment: no response, i changed resultJson to result

Comment: the result is null all the time , also the SuccesMsg action is not called

Answer (score 3):

Add **dataType: "json"** to your $.ajax call or use the shorthand: **$.getJSON**.

Also check that your controller handles the response returns in state http 200 (OK).

For debugging, you could add **complete: function(){alert('complete');}** to see if the request completes or not. Good debugging tools (add-ons) for Firefox are Live http headers and Firebug.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the programming language your controller is composed of so I'll suggest also to check how the JSON is composed. JQuery version 1.4 and up (if I recall correctly) accepts only strictly formed JSON: http://json.org/

Comment: the alert complete does not come up:( i added the datatype and changed:

Answer (score 2):

i think u need to specify as below in your jquery.ajax :

dataType: 'json'

```
 $("#but").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/SuccesMsg",
                dataType: 'json', // change code
                type: 'POST',
                data: "",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result['Success'] == true) {
                        alert('success');
                    }

                    else
                    { alert('no'); }
                },
                error: function (err) { alert('error') }
            });
        });
```

Comment: changed resultJson to result[..]

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this and it should work. You want

```
if (result.Success) {....}
```

instead of

```
if (resultJson['Success'] == true) {..}
```

So entire example

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SuccesMsg()
    {
        return Json(
            new
            {
                Success = true
            }
        );
    } 

$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/SuccesMsg',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.Success) {
            alert('success');
        } else {
            alert('no');
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

You should also specify the dataType but not required:
http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

Answer (score 0):

In MVC2 use JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet has said [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx)

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SuccesMsg()
    {
        return Json(new { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
```